# How do I scrape data from an ArcGIS Online map?

Tags: web-services, web-scraping, arcgis, esri, arcgis-online

I want to scrape the data from an ArcGIS map. The following map has a popup when we click the red features. How do I access that data programmatically?

Link : https://cslt.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=2c9f3e737cbf4f6faf2eb956fa26cdc5

Answer (score 36):

*Note: Please respect the **access and use constraints** of any ArcGIS Online item you access. When in doubt, don't save a copy of someone else's data.*

The [ArcGIS Online REST interface](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/) makes it relatively simple to get the data behind ArcGIS Online items. You need to use an environment that can make HTTP requests and parse JSON text. Most current programming languages either have these capabilities built in or have libraries available with these capabilities.

Here's a general workflow that your code could follow.

1. Use the app ID and the [item data endpoint](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/item-data.htm) to see the app's JSON text:

   https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/2c9f3e737cbf4f6faf2eb956fa26cdc5/data
2. Search that text for `webmap` and see that the app uses the following web maps:

   - `d2b4a98c39fd4587b99ac0878c420125`
   - `7b1af1752c3a430184fbf7a530b5ec65`
   - `c6e9d07e4c2749e4bfe23999778a3153`
3. Look at the item data endpoint for any of those web maps:

   https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/d2b4a98c39fd4587b99ac0878c420125/data
4. The list of `operationalLayers` specifies the feature layer URLs from which you could harvest data. For example:

   https://services2.arcgis.com/gWRYLIS16mKUskSO/arcgis/rest/services/VHR_Areas/FeatureServer/0
5. Then just run a [query](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm) with a `where` of `0=0` (or whatever you want) and an `outFields` of `*`:

   https://services2.arcgis.com/gWRYLIS16mKUskSO/arcgis/rest/services/VHR_Areas/FeatureServer/0/query?where=0%3D0&outFields=%2A&f=json

   Use `f=html` instead if you want to see a human-readable request form and results.

   Note that feature services have a limit of how many features you can get per request, so you will probably want to filter by geometry or attribute values. [Read the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm) to learn everything you can do with feature service queries.

Comment: yes! i got your point regarding the data rights!
Data was required for educational purposes with the permission of the city lake authorities! and thanks alot your answer did helped alot.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I was looking for data sources [here](https://instnsp.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/5eced796595b4ee585bcdba03e30c127).  

Found no `webmap`, just `mapWidget`, then `datasets.dataSource.id` – which looks like this: _1200f3f1-8f72-4ea6-af16-14f19e9a4517_ – it doesn't seem to work with _/sharing/rest/content/items/<itemId>/data_ requests

Comment: Yes, this answer is valid. The item you're looking at is a dashboard, which is a different structure than the story map that the OP asked about. In the [dashboard item data](https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/5eced796595b4ee585bcdba03e30c127/data), there are three `mapWidget` objects, each with an `itemId` that is a web map item ID. You can use any of those items' data ([here](https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/bbf83b52ae774f2783e8f685d1d43b21/data), for example; the other two seem almost identical to me) and start at step 3 in this answer.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful!

Comment: That's great that this answer is helping people, even if it was not marked as the accepted answer yet. 

Comment: is it possible to scrape the data of a map like this? -  https://sig.sea.gob.cl/mapaLineasBaseEIA/   - it doesn't have an arcgis.com url, thanks

Comment: I'm having some problems to retrieve data from a dashboard but this is REALLY helpful