# Scraping from an ArcGis Database doesn't return data?

Tags: json, rest, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to scrape age data from this map (go to the "Cases By County" section and click the right arrow once): https://samford.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/b1ea36da38064bb499b77f5e76ee7bf0.

With tremendous help from ([How do I scrape data from an ArcGIS Online map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161492/how-do-i-scrape-data-from-an-arcgis-online-map)), I've done the following. First, I went to [the app json text](https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b1ea36da38064bb499b77f5e76ee7bf0/data). I extracted the id of the first mapWidget object, which is *b0f4656b5402467d9d94dc5440be4b4a*, and then went to https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b0f4656b5402467d9d94dc5440be4b4a/data. For testing, I decided to try to extract age data, so I found the `operationalLayers` array of feature layers from that page, and determined the url to be https://services7.arcgis.com/4RQmZZ0yaZkGR1zy/ArcGIS/rest/services/Statewide_COVID19_CONFIRMED_DEMOG_PUBLIC/FeatureServer/0. From there, I tried querying `0=0`, which returns [this](https://services7.arcgis.com/4RQmZZ0yaZkGR1zy/ArcGIS/rest/services/Statewide_COVID19_CONFIRMED_DEMOG_PUBLIC/FeatureServer/0/query?where=0%3D0&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnCentroid=false&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=html&token=). But as you can see, it returns map-related results, instead of numerical data that you can see in the chart.

This whole interface seems very foreign to me, so could someone help query the data the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly you want to obtain? .. use you example if you want

Comment: could i get a bump on this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is your goal, so I will give you a couple of examples.

First, If you are not interesting in the geometry, you just need to set `returnGeometry=false`.

Examples:

1. retrieve every record, fields `AgeGroup`, `AgeGroup_Counts`
2. retrieve records of `AgeGroup` equal `>=65`
3. retrieve records of `AgeGroup` `>=65` and `0-4`
4. retrieve records where `AgeGroup_Counts` is greatest that `10000`

I think you get the idea. This are really simple queries, only using `where` field. The rest API is more powerful that this, but for simple queries sometimes this is enough.

[1](https://services7.arcgis.com/4RQmZZ0yaZkGR1zy/ArcGIS/rest/services/Statewide_COVID19_CONFIRMED_DEMOG_PUBLIC/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=AgeGroup%2C+AgeGroup_Counts&returnGeometry=false&f=json)
[2](https://services7.arcgis.com/4RQmZZ0yaZkGR1zy/ArcGIS/rest/services/Statewide_COVID19_CONFIRMED_DEMOG_PUBLIC/FeatureServer/0/query?where=AgeGroup%3D%27%3E%3D+65%27&outFields=AgeGroup%2C+AgeGroup_Counts&returnGeometry=false&f=json)
[3](https://services7.arcgis.com/4RQmZZ0yaZkGR1zy/ArcGIS/rest/services/Statewide_COVID19_CONFIRMED_DEMOG_PUBLIC/FeatureServer/0/query?where=AgeGroup+IN+%28%27%3E%3D+65%27%2C%270-4%27%29&outFields=AgeGroup%2C+AgeGroup_Counts&returnGeometry=false&f=json)
[4](https://services7.arcgis.com/4RQmZZ0yaZkGR1zy/ArcGIS/rest/services/Statewide_COVID19_CONFIRMED_DEMOG_PUBLIC/FeatureServer/0/query?where=AgeGroup_Counts+%3E+10000&outFields=AgeGroup%2C+AgeGroup_Counts&returnGeometry=false&f=json)