# How to scraping/Extract data from ESRI Arcgis from website?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, arcgis, esri

I was trying to extract data from an ESRI map embedded in a website. The objective would be by introducing geographic coordinates to be able to access the values ​​present on the map.

I leave here a print of the map and the respective address. I just cannot understand which method I should use since the map is embedded in the site. What processes should I use?

*for academic purposes

- https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/default.jsp

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I must admit, I am not quite sure what you are after in terms of extracting data.  I visited the site, and it is a pretty basic embedded web map created using the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/), albeit wrapped in JSP.  The web map is consuming some publicly accessible Esri services (World_Imagery, World_Boundaries_and_Places), and some non-public organizational services from [www.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt](http://www.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt).

It seems to me you are interested in geocoding.  The pointer/marker on your map was looked up using Esri's [ArcGIS Online Geocoding Service](https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/):

> You have reached the home for the ArcGIS Online Geocoding Service. Use
> it to turn addresses into coordinates, coordinates into addresses, or
> to locate a point-of-interest.
>
> If you are a developer, detailed documentation for using this service
> in your application is available in the [ArcGIS Online Geocoding
> Service Help](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/geocoding/).
>
> If you are an ArcGIS for Desktop user, you can use this service for
> finding addresses interactively or [geocoding a table of addresses](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geocoding/convert-a-table-to-locations-on-the-map.htm).

Since I am not quite clear what you are trying to do, this is about all I can offer for now.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Please respect **data ownership**. When in doubt, don't save a copy of someone else's data.*

It sounds like you want to extract the polygon data in this map. The web app is making requests like this:

https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/identify?f=json&tolerance=0&returnGeometry=false&imageDisplay=400%2C400%2C96&geometry=%7B%22x%22%3A-886651.3363331377%2C%22y%22%3A4443259.272690449%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&sr=102100&mapExtent=-887053.8250602124%2C4442583.282721534%2C-885178.7292100423%2C4443968.70385924&layers=all%3A0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4&callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript11._jsonpCallback

You can remove the `callback` parameter if you just want the data:

https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/identify?f=json&tolerance=0&returnGeometry=false&imageDisplay=400%2C400%2C96&geometry=%7B%22x%22%3A-886651.3363331377%2C%22y%22%3A4443259.272690449%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&sr=102100&mapExtent=-887053.8250602124%2C4442583.282721534%2C-885178.7292100423%2C4443968.70385924&layers=all%3A0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4

However, if you just go to that link, you will get an error about a missing or incorrect referrer. To overcome that, you will need to add a header called `Referer` with value `https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/default.jsp`. You can do that in a script or in an application like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), but you will not be able to do it in your own web app.

To view the available layers: https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer?f=json (with the `Referer` header I mentioned)

To view metadata about a single layer, use the following URL. Replace the 0 in `/0/` with a different layer ID to get a different layer. https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/0?f=json (with the `Referer` header I mentioned)

To [query](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-map-service-layer-.htm) one of those layers to get the data, use the following URL to get everything, or add some query parameters if you want to filter the data. Replace the 0 in `/0/` with a different layer ID to get a different layer. https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/0/query?f=json&outFields=*&where=0%3D0 (with the `Referer` header I mentioned)

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50213419/720773